# How to call a function that returns a generic slice type on Rust

Tags: rust

I'm reading the following code [from here](https://github.com/zmwangx/rust-ffmpeg/blob/master/src/util/frame/video.rs#L252):

```
#[inline]
pub fn plane<T: Component>(&self, index: usize) -> &[T] {
    if index >= self.planes() {
        panic!("out of bounds");
    }

    if !<T as Component>::is_valid(self.format()) {
```

As you see, the `plane` function returns a slice of a generic type. Does that mean I need to **always** call this function like this: `plane::<SomeType>::(my_index)`?

The problem is that I don't know which type to use, it's not a type for the entire struct, just for this function and others.

For example, I saw

```
unsafe impl Component for [u8; 3] {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn is_valid(format: format::Pixel) -> bool {
        format == format::Pixel::RGB24 || format == format::Pixel::BGR24
    }
}
```

Does that mean `T` can be `[u8; 3]` and thus `plane` can return `&[&[u8; 3]]`?

So should I call `self.plane::<u8>(index)`? I tried that but I get `wrong number of type arguments: expected 0, found 1` on `u8`. Also I don't think `&[&[u8; 3]]` is right.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean I need to **always** call this function like this: `plane::<SomeType>(my_index)`?

No, if Rust can infer `SomeType`, you don't have to provide it explicitly. If you're e.g. assigning the result of `plane` to a variable that you've given a type, you don't have to provide it in the call.

> Does that mean `T` can be `[u8; 3]` and thus plane can return `&[&[u8; 3]]`?

If `T` is `[u8; 3]`, plane returns `&[[u8; 3]]`.